# Hibernate Java 8 ZonedDateTime

Tags: hibernate, jpa, java-8, java-time, zoneddatetime

I am using Hibernate and JPA to store my data in a database. 
Now I would like to save a `ZonedDateTime` from `java.time`.

The problem is, Hibernate does only ever persist the date and time. It does not care about the `ZoneId` or the offset.

Is there any way to persuade Hibernate to persist that information?

Comment: Do you try to save it as a TimeStamp in the database?

Comment: Which database engine are you using? MySQL, for example, can't store the zone, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: I can confirm this issue with `postgres 9.5.10` and `hibernate 5.2.12`. The automatically created column type is `timestamp without timezone` whereas I would expect it to be `timestamp with timezone`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34008907/hibernate-5-zoneddatetime-postgresql-inlcude-time-zone-and-the-offset

Answer (score 4):

hibernate 5 support java8 datetime types by adding  hibernate-java8 dependancy but in version 5.2.10 this moved to hibernate core

(deprecated - use hibernate-core instead) Support for Java8-specific features - mainly Java8 Date/Time (JSR 310)

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-java8 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

for more information about hibernate and datetime see this

```
import java.time.Instant;

@Column(name = "reset_date")
private Instant resetDate = null;


setResetDate(Instant.now());
```

https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-5-date-and-time/

Comment: This is true, but doesn't answer the question which is about the Zone part of a ZonedDateTime.

Comment: In which database you test it?

Comment: @aliakbarazizkhani thus far i tested it in h2 and mssql

Comment: @Column(name = "reset_date")
private Instant resetDate = null;